# Projection problem with linear and boxes constraints

Tags: optimization, projection

Given a fixed point $y$, I would like to minimize $||x-y||^2$ subject to $Ax=b$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$. It's like a projection of y onto the subset $\left\lbrace x | Ax=b, 0\leq x \leq 1 \right\rbrace$.

Thanks for the help!